# How to extract ID3 tags from mp3 using FFmpeg-libav

Tags: kotlin, ffmpeg, libav

Is there a way to extract ID3 tags using ffmpeg-libav?
I have already tried the code below but it does not extract anything:

```kotlin
fun extractMetadata(mp3FilePath: String) {
    avformat.av_register_all()

    val formatContext = AVFormatContext(null)
    if (avformat.avformat_open_input(formatContext, mp3FilePath, null, null) < 0) {
        println("Failed to open input file")
        return
    }

    if (avformat.avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, null) < 0) {
        println("Failed to retrieve stream information")
        avformat.avformat_close_input(formatContext)
        return
    }

    var metadataEntry: AVDictionaryEntry? = null
    while (true) {
        metadataEntry = avformat.av_dict_get(formatContext.metadata, "", metadataEntry, avformat.AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX)
        if (metadataEntry == null) {
            break
        }
        val key = metadataEntry.key().getString()
        val value = metadataEntry.value().getString()
        println("Key: $key, Value: $value")
    }

    avformat.avformat_close_input(formatContext)
}
```

By the way this code is written in Kotlin and using `org.bytedecoe.ffmpeg-platform` lib which is a wrapper for libav. You can give me C++ code and i will be able convert it to kotlin code with ease.

Comment: 0. What is your ffmpeg version?
1. Did you make sure that `av_dict_get` is definitely called at least once?
2. Did you check that the entry mp3 file definitely contains ID3?
3. What will the results be like if you use `av_dict_iterate` instead of `av_dict_get`

Comment: `av_register_all()` is deprecated in ffmpeg 4, so I guess you might be using really old ffmpeg.